# Popen multi line read

Tags: python, popen

I'm pretty new to python I have been using popen to execute commands but I am expecting a multiple line response and I need to use each line separately.

I have the following code that I got from a tutorial.

```
pipe = os.popen('dir')
        for line in pipe:
            print '--------------space---------------------'
            print pipe.readLine()
```

but know I keep getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readLine'

does anyone have any advice for me, or an idea of how to rather improve this.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your syntax `readline` uses a lower case l.

However I'd like to know what you're trying to accomplish. If you just want to print each line then you should just change `print pipe.readline()` --> `print line`.

```
import os
pipe = os.popen('dir')
for line in pipe:
    print '--------------space---------------------'
    print line
```

Your `for` loop is already reading the output line by line from `popen`. In fact if you attempt to call `pipe.readline()` mid-iteration it is illegal and your code will raise an exception.

To illustrate the exception you can try running this:

```
import os
pipe = os.popen('dir')
for line in pipe:
    print '--------------space---------------------'
    print pipe.readline()
```

Comment: Actually, it will run perfectly fine with the `readline()`, but you'll only see every other line.

Comment: @glibdud No it will not. Try it yourself. You'll see the following, tested in python 2.7: `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`

Comment: Odd, I did try it and it runs fine for me.

Comment: @glibdud Interesting. I posted the code I tested with in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark Beilfuss. That helped.

I was trying to get the information to append to array and display in my front end. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Alex.JvV No problem. If I've answered your question please select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use subprocess module, it has a lot of useful functions to interact with other processes. check_output or call will do the job

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output('dir', universal_newlines=True)
```